# Understanding of not() function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I do not understand why I am still getting element `<li class=".item-2">` with red background.
Please take a look a my code and provide me some tips.

```
<ul class="level-1">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II
        <ul class="level-2">
            <li class="item-a">A</li>
            <li class="item-b">B
                <ul class="level-3">
                    <li class="item-1">1</li>
                    <li class="item-2">2 .item-2</li>
                    <li class="item-3">3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item-c">C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>

$("li.item-ii").find('li').not($(".item-2")).css("background-color", "red");
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k3cqS/1/

Comment: well... there are 5 li's that match your selector, so i expect 5 to be red. (keep in mind that a red parent will make all children red too unless otherwise specified on each li http://jsfiddle.net/k3cqS/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find('li')` matches the parent LI as well, so excluding the child doesn't matter when the parent has a red background.

You end up with this

```
<ul class="level-1">
    <li class="item-i">I</li>
    <li class="item-ii">II
        <ul class="level-2">
            <li class="item-a" style="background-color: red;">A</li>

            <!-- The below element is red, and is the parent element -->
            <li class="item-b" style="background-color: red;">B
                <ul class="level-3">
                    <li class="item-1" style="background-color: red;">1</li>

                    <!-- so it doesn't matter if this isn't red -->
                    <li class="item-2">2 .item-2</li>
                    <li class="item-3" style="background-color: red;">3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="item-c" style="background-color: red;">C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

`.item-2` is actually transparent, so the parents background is showing.